Installing Storm Door on Recessed Door Frame with Sidelight and Transom Windows
I plan to install a storm door on my front exterior door, which is part of a single unit with sidelight windows and a transom window above. The door frame is recessed inside the transom frame and the bottom sill plate, making it an uneven surface for mounting the storm door frame. I wonder if anyone has experience or advice on evening out the surface to ensure a secure and level storm door installation. What materials or techniques would be best to create a flat mounting surface? My current thought is to glue and screw in some 2x4 furring strips to the door frame sides but would appreciate any other suggestions. In this case, is pressure-treated lumber preferred, or since I'm painting it to match the frame can I use "regular" lumber?


Go the extra mile and clad the exposed edges of the furring with matching aluminum wrapped on three sides to eliminate future maintenance.

You could simply use some spacers (recommend PVC "lumber") to space out the jambs so there's a flush surface on top and sides.
